# Is it possible to specify an arbitrary list of varags in a generic method?

Tags: generics, kotlin

I am trying to write an interface for REST controllers called `GetOne` right now this consists of a single method `getOne`

```kotlin
fun <T> getOne(vararg args : Any) : ResponseEntity<RestResponse<T>>
```

Ideally I would like to be able to implement this method in any REST controller that has a method for getting one item by id.

While my return type works fine, the method itself can have any number of arguments that are annotated in Spring to map / serialize the fields to the RequestBody / Path Variables / Query Parameters.

I thought I would be able to represent this in my interface as `varargs` , but this just results in the compiler expecting me to specifically have varargs in my method signature.

Is there a proper way to express this, or can you not do this in kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need an interface for the controllers? 
If you want some common functionality for the implementations (like logging the ID param), you could use Spring AOP.

Comment: Mostly for the sake of consistency, the project is fairly large and I believe that interfaces will make it easier to enforce naming conventions / simple concepts.